# multiple checkbox delete mysqli

Tags: php, checkbox, mysqli

I'm trying to get multiple deletion capability, and this is what I have so far:

```
<?php
  echo '<h3>Welcome to your profile, '. $_SESSION['first_name'] . '</h3>';

  require_once ('../mysqli_connect.php'); //Connect to the db

  // Make the query

  $q = "SELECT upload_id, title, genre, length, created, views
        FROM upload
        WHERE owner_id =". $_SESSION['user_id'] ."
        ORDER BY title ASC";


  $r = mysqli_query ($dbc, $q); // Run the query

  if($r) {
    ?>
    <table align="center" cellspacing="3" cellpadding="3" width="75%">
      <tr>
        <td align="left"><b>Title</b></td>
        <td align="left"><b>Genre</b></td>
        <td align="left"><b>Pages</b></td>
        <td align="left"><b>Submitted</b></td>
        <td align="left"><b>Views</b></td>';
          <form action="/nbproject/newwriter_profile.php" method="post">
          <?php
            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($r,MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
              echo '<tr><td align="left">' 
                . $row['title'] . '</td><td align="left">'
                . $row['genre'] . '</td><td align="left">'
                . $row['length'] . '</td><td align="left">'
                . $row['created'] . '</td><td align="left">'
                . $row['views'] . '</td><td align="left">'
                . '<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]"'
                . 'id="checkbox[]"  value='.$row['$upload_id'] //this upload id is auto-increment (see first note)
                .' />'.' </td>'. '</tr>';
            }
          ?>
    </table>
    <input type="submit" name="delete" value="Delete" align="right"/>
  </form>
  <?php
    mysqli_free_result ($r); // Free up the resources
  } else { // If it did not run okay
    // Public Message:
    echo '<p class="error">Your submissions could not be retrieved.  We apologize for any inconvenience.</p>';
    // Debugging message:
    echo '<p>' . mysqli_error($dbc) . '<br /><br />Query: ' . $q . '</p>';
  } // End of if ($r) IF.

  mysqli_close($dbc); // Close the database connection

  if($_POST['delete']) {
    require_once ('../mysqli_connect.php'); //Connect to the db

    $checkbox = $_POST['checkbox']; //from name="checkbox[]"
    $countCheck = count($_POST['checkbox']);

    for($i=0;$i<$countCheck;$i++) {
      $del_id  = $checkbox[$i];
      //----------------------------------
      $sql = "DELETE from `upload` where `upload_id` = $del_id AND `owner_id` = {$_SESSION['user_id']}";
      $result = $mysqli->query($sql) or die(mysqli_error($mysqli)); //added session information after hearing about google spider armageddon scenarios
    }

    if($result) {
      header('Location: newwriter_profile.php');
    } else {
      echo "Error: ".mysqli_error();
    }
  }
?>
```

1st Note: Basically the registered user is greeted by their profile page which shows them their uploads and some upload info.  I'd like a checkbox alongside each upload and a delete button wherever else on the page.  So I tried this.

Right now it will redirect with no errors and nothing is deleted.  Also, hitting Delete without a checkbox selected returns an error.  Thanks for the help in advance, solving this issue will also solve another I am having and will be a huge relief.

I can't think of a way to get the upload id to be linked to the checkbox.  My brain hurts.

EDIT: This is the current output of the viewsource for the checkbox, using dcoder's recommendation and the vardump test.    input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" id="checkbox[]"  value= "" />

vardump test output:  array(3) { [0]=> string(0) "" [1]=> string(0) "" [2]=> string(0) "" }

EDIT: delete functions are currently as follows:

```
    function submit_delete() {
    if($_POST['delete'] && $_POST['checkbox[]']) { //Check to see if a delete command         has been submitted.
//This will dump your checkbox array to your screen if the submit works.
//You can manually check to see if you're getting the correct array with values
//var_dump($_POST['checkbox']);//Comment this out once it's working.
deleteUploads($_POST['checkbox[]']);
    }
   }


   function deleteUploads ($id_array) {
   if (count($id_array) <= 0) { return; }//bail if its empty
   $delete_success = false;
   foreach ($id_array as &$id) {
   $sql = "DELETE from `upload` where `upload_id`=$id AND `owner_id`=   {$_SESSION['user_id']}";
   $result = $mysqli->query($sql) or die(mysqli_error($mysqli));
   if ($result) { $delete_success = true; }
   }

    if($delete_success) {
   header('Location: newwriter_profile.php');
  } else {
  echo "Error: ".mysqli_error();
  }
  }


//Test deleteUploads (remove once you know the function is working)
//$test_ids = array();
//$test_ids[] = 5;//make sure this id is in the db
//$test_ids[] = 7;//this one too
submit_delete();
deleteUploads($id_array);//should remove ids 10 and 9//

mysqli_close($dbc);
```

EDIT:  Currently is as follows:

```
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($r,MYSQLI_ASSOC))
    {
        echo '<tr><td align="left">' .
        $row['title'] . '</td><td align="left">'
        . $row['genre'] . '</td><td align="left">'
        . $row['length'] . '</td><td align="left">'
        . $row['created'] . '</td><td align="left">'
        . $row['views'] . '</td><td align="left">' //. var_dump($row) //dump row value              for testing
        . '<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]"'. 'id="checkbox[]"  value=               "'.$row['upload_id'].'"'.' />'.' </td>'. '</tr>';
```

commented out vardump, shows that each checkbox is getting the correct upload_id...

```
    function submit_delete() {
   if(!is_null($_POST['delete']) && !is_null($_POST['checkbox[]'])) { //Check to see if              delete command has been submitted.
//This will dump your checkbox array to your screen if the submit works.
//You can manually check to see if you're getting the correct array with values
//var_dump($_POST['checkbox']);//Comment this out once it's working.
deleteUploads($_POST['checkbox[]']);

   }
   else {
   echo "Error: submit_delete called without valid checkbox delete.";
    }
   }


   function deleteUploads ($id_array) {
    if (count($id_array) <= 0) {   echo "Error: No deletes in id_array!";    var_dump($id_array); return; }//bail if its empty
   $delete_success = false;
   foreach ($id_array as &$id) {
   $sql = "DELETE FROM `upload` WHERE `upload_id`=$id AND `owner_id`=   {$_SESSION['user_id']}";
    $result = $mysqli->query($sql) or die(mysqli_error($mysqli));
   if ($result) { $delete_success = true; }
  }

  if($delete_success) {
 header('Location: newwriter_profile.php');
  } else {
  echo "Error: ".mysqli_error();
 }
}


//Test deleteUploads (remove once you know the function is working)
//$test_ids = array();
//$test_ids[] = 5;//make sure this id is in the db
//$test_ids[] = 7;//this one too
submit_delete();
//deleteUploads($id_array);//should remove ids 10 and 9//

mysqli_close($dbc);
```

on page load, I get the error "submit_delete called..."
after I tick some boxes and hit delete... I get the same error. Bailing out on the $_POST['checkbox[]'] and getting a NULL value.

Comment: Made an edit to your post cleaning up the code. Note that you had a lot of extraneous open and close php tags, and erratic use of echoed strings versus unprocessed markup. You should find a style that works for you and stick to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem.  I ran a grant * permission statement in MySQL after exhausting every other option. Apparently I had created the database user prior to creating the Uploads table.  Thanks all for the help

Answer (score 1):

The problem is here:

```
'<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]"'
. 'id="checkbox[]"  value='.$row['$upload_id']
.' />'
```

Change this to the following:

```
'<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]"'
. 'id="checkbox[]"  value="'.$row['upload_id'] . '"'
.' />'
```

You're missing quotes(`"`) around the value, and you're outputting the wrong index.

---

Also, please use [bind variables](http://us.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) for embedding dynamic elements into SQL queries, and [escape dynamic input](http://us.php.net/htmlspecialchars) before outputting it to the page.

Comment: I changed the checkbox as you suggested, currently getting: input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" id="checkbox[]"  value= "" />  as viewsource output.

Comment: Then you should `var_dump($row)` before printing it - it doesn't look like the `upload_id` column has any value.

Answer (score 0):

I've broken your functionality out into functions you can call. The former function will help you test that you're getting the right values. You can manually populate an array with values you know are in the database to check the latter function.

```
function submit_delete() {
  if($_POST['delete'] && $_POST['checkbox']) { //Check to see if a delete command has been submitted.
    //This will dump your checkbox array to your screen if the submit works. 
    //You can manually check to see if you're getting the correct array with values
    var_dump($_POST['checkbox']);//Comment this out once it's working. 
    deleteUploads($_POST['checkbox']);
  } else { 
    echo "Error: submit_delete called without valid checkbox delete.";
  }
}

function deleteUploads ($id_array) {
  if (count($id_array) <= 0) { //bail if its empty
    echo "Error: No deletes in id_array!";
    return; 
  }
  $delete_success = false;
  foreach ($id_array as &$id) {
    $sql = "DELETE from `upload` where `upload_id`=$id AND `owner_id`={$_SESSION['user_id']}";
    $result = $mysqli->query($sql) or die(mysqli_error($mysqli));
    if ($result) { $delete_success = true; }
  }

  if($delete_success) {
    header('Location: newwriter_profile.php');
  } else {
    echo "Error: ".mysqli_error();
  }
}


//Test deleteUploads (remove once you know the function is working)
$test_ids = array();
$test_ids[] = 10;//make sure this id is in the db
$test_ids[] = 9;//this one too
deleteUploads($test_ids);//should remove ids 10 and 9
```

Comment: I added your functions to my code.  It is currently outputting: array(3) { [0]=> string(1) "/" [1]=> string(1) "/" [2]=> string(1) "/" }   to my screen on checkbox submission.  Database id values for my checked values should be 5,6 and 7 respectively. I'm not 100% sure if I'm reading the vardump correctly but should string(1) be string(5), string(6), string(7) ?   I am using 3 database rows as a test, checking each box, upload_id's of 5,6,7

Comment: That confirms that it's not constructing the values correctly. When the page is open, what is the actual html show for the checkboxes? (view source). Can you add that to the question?

Comment: current output for the checkboxes is:  input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" id="checkbox[]"  value= "" />    in the viewsource.  This reflects the changes suggested by DCoder below.

Comment: I am finally getting the correct values sent to the checkboxes, how do I alter your functions to perform the real delete?  I commented out the test array block as well as var_dump, no deleting is taking place though. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you getting the string "Error: " in your output somewhere? Make sure to look at the html source, as it may not be visible.

Comment: No I dont see the error message in the viewsource or on the normal php page... I believe it's hitting the bail condition but I dont see how.

Comment: I made an update to both functions, to provide an error if it doesn't find the correct POST parameters. If you put that in, does that display an error on the page?

Comment: Getting the "no deletes in id_array error.  On page load, both of them show up.  After ticking a few boxes and hitting delete the submit delete call error goes away while the "no deletes" error is displayed twice

Comment: Note that 'submit_delete' calls 'deleteUploads', so you don't need to call it twice (as shown in your edit). Add `var_dump($id_array);` to the code after the 'no deletes' error message and see what you get.

Comment: On page load: Error: No deletes in id_array!NULL

Comment: That means this clause `if($_POST['delete'] && $_POST['checkbox[]'])` isn't working, specifically that $_POST['checkbox[]'] is returning null. Try:  `if(!is_null($_POST['delete']) && !is_null($_POST['checkbox[]']))`

Comment: it is still bailing on the if statement for !is_null on $_POST['checkbox[]']     error: submit_delete called without valid checkbox delete...  edited current code above

Comment: id_array isnt being assigned the correct values from $_POST, not sure how to act on this.